# Overflow encountered in exponential

Tags: python

I have this piece of code:

```
from __future__ import division
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import numpy as np
import copy
import random
import math

A_bb=9.2572264*10**(-45)
E_bb=4.8043478/10**11

x=np.arange(0,20,0.01)

def func(x,T):
    x=np.array(x)
    return A_bb*(10**x)**3/(np.exp(10**x*E_bb/T)-1)
popt,pcov=curve_fit(func,frec, Flux_57442_27165)
print (popt)
```

Basically I want to fit a blackbody curve to some data points. But I get this error:

```
overflow encountered in exp w=A_bb*(10**x)**3/(np.exp(10**x*E_bb/T1)-1)
```

The value of T I expect is of order 10^4. What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: a) Check your code. Make sure this formula is being evaluated the way you want. b) If an actual overflow is really being encountered, use the [`long`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#long) datatype instead.

Comment: You are calling `curve_fit`, but you aren't defining it anywhere. Is that sample an actual program that you've copy-pasted into your question, or is it bits and pieces of a program? See [mcve] to see how good example programs lead to excellent answers.

Comment: I really doubt you have the [correct equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation#Equations). Namely, for the frequency, instead of calculating `v`, you're calculating `10**v`. No surprise you get overflow errors.

Comment: @Robᵩ sorry it is just a piece of code curve_fit is imported

Comment: @Reti43 frequency is of order 10^14-10^15. x is going form 0 to 20 and then I take 10^x

Comment: And I think you meant to write `(x*10e14)**3` for the first part and `x*10e14` for the second.

Answer (score 0):

Python's native `int` type, from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#numeric-types-int-float-long-complex) is only capable of storing integers upto 2^32:

> Plain integers (also just called integers) are implemented using long in C, which gives them at least 32 bits of precision

To get around this, Python also provides the `long` datatype:

> Long integers have unlimited precision.

Simply apply `long()` to `T` if an overflow is being encountered:

```
T = long(T)
```

and hope that it works.

---

If even that fails, I strongly recommend using [`numpy`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/index.html) instead, which has [much more powerful datatypes](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.types.html).